# Objective C - Deallocate Class from Within Delegate Method

Tags: objective-c

If a class calls its delegate as its last responsibility:

```
if ([videoWebViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(accessDeniedByUser)])
    [videoWebViewDelegate accessDeniedByUser];
```

Is there a way to nil the pointer to the class without raising an exception:

```
videoWebView = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
videoWebView.delegate = nil;
videoWebView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the delegate solution above but no cigar.  In the end, it turns out it was trying to call - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex after I had nilled the pointer.

My solution was to replace - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex with didDismissWithButtonIndex, which worked just fine for my purposes.  So, now didDismissWithButtonIndex calls the delegate methods, where I nil the pointer, and there are no further calls to the nilled object.

Thx for reply.